# How can I make a reading scroll bar with css?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

So I was trying to make a scroll bar for blog but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before**: `.my-element { background: red; }`

**After**: `.my-element { background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5); }`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Here's a demo:

```css
.my-element {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element"></div>
```

Comment: @FedericoMigueletto I am not sure what you mean.  it would be really helpful if you included some of your code in the original question.

Comment: @FedericoMigueletto, if that's what you think is more appropriate, simply change ".my-element" to "#my-element" in the CSS, and "class=" to "id=" in the HTML.